# Visual COBOL for 2010 visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, cobol

I just installed trail version of Visual COBOL with visual studio 2010 from Micro Focus. I am trying to compile one of my old COBOL programs into .NET assembly. When I compile, it creates .IDY file exension file in the bin floder. I want to decompile assembly to C# code. Is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks..

Comment: Are you trying to translate COBOL to C# by this stunt?

Comment: I just installed it to for visual studio. Do you know where it stores all of the code if you put buttons, menus and other components on the form. Normally in C# has separate file that stores this information and you actually can add code in manually if you know what you are doing. I would think that Visual Cobol would have the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

[Note: post from Micro Focus]

As the previous poster noted, the IDY file is only used to support the debugger.

If this is a managed code project (and you can create both managed and unmanaged (native) code in VS 2010 with Visual COBOL), then you will the assemblies in standard MSIL just like any other .NET language. Bear in mind this is not code that's intended to be human-readable and depends on the Micro Focus COBOL runtime so you can't reverse engineer the code to some other language such as C# (there may also be license agreement issues).

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming it to *.dll, and load it into [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm).  If that fails, MicroFocus is doing something funky and that's not a .NEt assembly.  This is probably not unreasonable.  The .IDY file could be some form of pcode, which is interpreted by some runtime (that is real .NET code)

Comment: thank you. I renamed file and trying to decompile using Reflector. I am getting 'object reference not set' error message. Any ideas?

Comment: That falls under "If that fails" as described above.

Answer (score 2):

The .idy file contains data for debugging, so using reflector on it will not work just like reflector does not work on .pdb files.